# Spearman correlation between two matrices of same dimensions

Tags: r, loops, matrix, correlation, psych

I have two matrices of equal dimensions (p and e) and I would like to make a spearman correlation between columns of the same name. I want to have the output of pair correlations in a matrix (M)

I used the `corr.test()` function from library Psych and here is what I did:

```
library(psych)
M <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=3,nrow=ncol(p)))
M[,1] <- as.character()
G <- colnames(p)
for(rs in 1:ncol(p){
      M[rs,1] <- G[rs]     
      cor <- corr.test(p[,rs],e[,rs],method="spearman",adjust="none")
      M[rs,2] <- cor$r
      M[rs,3] <- cor$p
}
```

But I get an error message:

```
Error in 1:ncol(y) : argument of length 0
```

Could you please show me what is wrong? or suggest another method?

Comment: @thelatemail has the proper solution; but in your code what would work is to change your corr.test line with `corr.test(as.data.frame(p[,rs]), as.data.frame(e[,rs]), method="spearman", adjust="none")`. The hint for this, from the error message, is that the function expects to have a two-dimensional data structure as x/y arguments.

Answer (score 7):

No need for all this looping and indexing etc:

```
# test data
p <- matrix(data = rnorm(100),nrow = 10)
e <- matrix(data = rnorm(100),nrow = 10)

cor <- corr.test(p, e, method="spearman", adjust="none")
data.frame(name=colnames(p), r=diag(cor$r), p=diag(cor$p))

#  name           r         p
#a    a  0.36969697 0.2930501
#b    b  0.16363636 0.6514773
#c    c -0.15151515 0.6760652
# etc etc
```

If the names of the matrices don't already match, then `match` them:

```
cor <- corr.test(p, e[,match(colnames(p),colnames(e))], method="spearman", adjust="none")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the two matrices are huge, it would take very long system.time to execute the function `corr.test()` on all possible pairs but the loop that finally worked is as follow:

```
    library(psych)
    M <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=3,nrow=ncol(p)))
    M[,1] <- as.character()
    G <- colnames(p)
    for(rs in 1:ncol(p){
          M[rs,1] <- G[rs]     
          cor <- corr.test(as.data.frame(p[,rs]),as.data.frame(e[,rs]),
method="spearman",adjust="none")
          M[rs,2] <- cor$r
          M[rs,3] <- cor$p
    }
```